# How can I make the value of the second option vary depending on the value of the first option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are currently modifying the code that changes the amount according to each option.

However, I would like to modify the 'value' of option 2 and 'value' of option 3 to change according to option 1.

For example, if option 1-1 is selected, the amount of 2-2 is -1, but if option 1-2 is selected, the amount of 2-2 is -2.

I would like the amount of the final TOTAL to be revised according to the revised value value.

```js
$('.form-item input').on('change', function() {
  // addition and subtraction here
  var $this;
  var sum = 0;

  $('.form-item input').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);

    if ($this[0].checked == true) {
      sum += parseInt($this.val());
    }

    $('.total span').html(sum.toLocaleString('en-US'));
  })
});
```

```css
.form-wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 480px;
}

.form-text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#fm-title {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#op-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #444;
}

.form-item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-item input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.form-type-radio {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.form-item input[type=radio]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 115px;
  width: 480px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 26px 45px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.form-item input[type=radio]+label {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #bbb;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-item input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #bbb;
  border-color: #444;
}

.total {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 65px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #555;
}

#bm-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #555;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#bm-text p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .form-wrap {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-item input[type=radio]+label {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 17px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .form-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #op-title {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .form-item {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  .form-type-radio {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .total {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #444;
  }
  #bm-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #bm-text p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrap">
  <div class="form-type-radio">
    <div class="form-text">OPTION 1</div>
    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="samename" value="1800000" class="form-radio" checked="checked">
      <label class="option" for="radio-1"><span id="op-title">1-1</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="samename" value="2500000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-2"><span id="op-title">1-2</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="samename" value="6000000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-3"><span id="op-title">1-3</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-type-radio">
    <div class="form-text">OPTION 2</div>
    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="samename1" value="0" class="form-radio" checked="checked">
      <label class="option" for="radio-4"><span id="op-title">2-1</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="samename1" value="-700000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-5"><span id="op-title">2-2</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-type-radio">
    <div class="form-text">OPTION 3</div>
    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-6" name="samename2" value="0" class="form-radio" checked="checked">
      <label class="option" for="radio-6"><span id="op-title">3-1</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-7" name="samename2" value="2000000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-7"><span id="op-title">3-2</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-8" name="samename2" value="-1300000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-8"><span id="op-title">3-3</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-9" name="samename2" value="-600000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-9"><span id="op-title">3-4</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-type-radio">
    <div class="form-text">OPTION 4</div>
    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-10" name="samename3" value="0" class="form-radio" checked="checked">
      <label class="option" for="radio-10"><span id="op-title">4-1</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-11" name="samename3" value="100000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-11"><span id="op-title">4-2</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-12" name="samename3" value="300000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-12"><span id="op-title">4-3</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-type-radio">
    <div class="form-text">OPTION 5</div>
    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-13" name="samename4" value="0" class="form-radio" checked="checked">
      <label class="option" for="radio-13"><span id="op-title">5-1</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-14" name="samename4" value="300000" class="form-radio">
      <label class="option" for="radio-14"><span id="op-title">5-2</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="total">TOTAL <span>0</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the calculations, but in this example I enable/disable two different fieldsets. Depending on the value of each radio button set the total is calculated. Notice that the radio buttons in the fieldset that is disabled are not included in the calculation.

```js
document.forms.form01.f0.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  ['f1','f2'].forEach(name => form[name].disabled = true);
  form[`f${e.target.value}`].disabled = false;
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let data = new FormData(form);
  let total = [...data.values()].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return accumulator + parseInt(currentValue);
    }, 0);
  console.log(total);
});
```

```css
fieldset:disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <fieldset name="f0">
    <legend>Option 1</legend>
    <label>1-1<input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" checked></label>
    <label>1-2<input type="radio" name="r1" value="2"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="f1">
    <legend>Option 2</legend>
    <label>2-1<input type="radio" name="r2" value="1" checked></label>
    <label>2-2<input type="radio" name="r2" value="2"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="f2" disabled>
    <legend>Option 2</legend>
    <label>3-1<input type="radio" name="r3" value="3" checked></label>
    <label>3-2<input type="radio" name="r3" value="4"></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```